# good practice to nest fxLayout containers?

Tags: css, html, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I recently started using angular/flex for the first time and not sure about layout container nesting.  In the below code the navigation tag is a angular-material sidenav that opens at the left and then pushes ther rest of the content to the right.  I noticed at this point (when I just got started it wasn't like this) that the sidenav seems to lag a bit lately when i'm opening/closing it.  it freezes half way through the animation for a few split seconds and then opens/closes completely.  I nested column and more row fxLayout containers in one row fxLayout container and think that might be the reason for the sidenav animation performance issue?  Am I over complicating things by nesting all these containers leading to performance issues?

my code:

```
<div fxLayout fxAlign="start start">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleSidenav()">
            <mat-icon aria-label="menu">
                <i class="material-icons">restaurant_menu</i>
            </mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span>POC Toolbar</span>            
        <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
        <div class="rhs">
            <mat-icon class="rhs-icon fa fa-home fa-lg"></mat-icon>
            <span class="rhs-item">Home</span>  

            <mat-icon class="rhs-icon fa fa-sign-out fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></mat-icon>
            <span class="rhs-item">Logout</span>

            <mat-icon class="rhs-icon fa fa-key fa-lg"></mat-icon>
            <span class="rhs-item">Password</span>

            <mat-icon class="rhs-icon fa fa-sitemap fa-lg"></mat-icon>
            <span class="rhs-item">Site map</span>          
        </div>  
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>

<div fxLayout="row"  fxLayoutAlign="start" fxLayoutGap="20px">
    <div fxFlex>
        <navigation [state]="showMenu"></navigation>
    </div>

    <div fxFlex="100%">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px">
            <div>
                <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eum iuvaret delicata at. Eu postea commodo persius mei. Id est semper constituto, ignota aperiri adversarium ne vix. Id est impetus suscipit, nulla meliore epicuri id eos. Ad pro modo albucius atomorum. At mel ullum libris debitis, in vero apeirian mediocrem mei.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>Sample Angular/Flex Column Layout</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout fxLayoutGap="15px">
            <div fxFlex="33%">              
                    <h3>Notes</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>we're using responsive css &amp; Angular(Angular-material &amp; Angular/flex) This allows us to show (or hide) things like the left menu and the number of columns displayed by dataTables.</li>
                        <li>The amount of "Custom" css we've used is actually very little, prefering rather to make use of the framework's built in features.</li>
                        <li>Angular reactive forms and validators should probably replace the generic php form.</li>
                        <li>No server side php is used.</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="33%">
                <h3>Example views</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Login Screen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home Page</a> &raquo; Ledger system &raquo; Sales ledger &raquo; Customer master files</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customer Master Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customer Master List</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">detail Customer Master</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">update Customer Master</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">detail Account</a> - Click on suburb <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lookup Screen(Generic)</a> - Click on suburb <i class="fa fa-search"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="33%">
                <h3>Keyboard Shortcuts</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><Ctrl + b: Go back/li>
                    <li>Ctrl + i: Launch info</li>
                    <li>Ctrl + h: Launch help</li>
                    <li>Ctrl + l: Show or hide menu</li>
                    <li>Ctrl + n: Add new item</li>
                    <li>Ctrl + p: Print</li>
                    <li>Ctrl + r: reload table data</li>
                    <li>Ctrl + <em>any other</em> page specific function you ned</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

my navigation component html:


<mat-sidenav-container position="start" class="custom-sidenav-container">

    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="false">
        Navigation
        <ul class="sn-list">
            <li>                    
                <mat-icon class="sn-item">
                    <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                </mat-icon>
                <a class="sn-item" href="#">Dashboard</a>       
            </li>
            <li>

                <mat-icon class="sn-item">
                    <i class="material-icons">archive</i>
                </mat-icon>             
                <span class="sn-item" [matMenuTriggerFor]="stockSystemMenu">Stok System</span>

                <mat-menu [overlapTrigger]="false" #stockSystemMenu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item>
                        <mat-icon class="sn-item">
                            <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
                        </mat-icon>
                        <span class="sn-item">Service 1</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item>
                        <mat-icon class="sn-item">
                            <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
                        </mat-icon>
                        <span class="sn-item">Service 2</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item>
                        <mat-icon class="sn-item">
                            <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
                        </mat-icon>
                        <span class="sn-item">Service 3</span>
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>
            </li>           
            <li>
                <mat-icon class="sn-item">
                    <i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i>
                </mat-icon>
                <span class="sn-item" [matMenuTriggerFor]="salesMenu">Sales / Purchases</span>
                <mat-menu [overlapTrigger]="false" #salesMenu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item>
                        <mat-icon class="sn-item">
                            <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
                        </mat-icon>
                        <span class="sn-item">Service 1</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item>
                        <mat-icon class="sn-item">
                            <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
                        </mat-icon>
                        <span class="sn-item">Service 2</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item>
                        <mat-icon class="sn-item">
                            <i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>
                        </mat-icon>
                        <span class="sn-item">Service 3</span>
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>         
            </li>       </ul>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <div class="sn-content">    
    </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: I can't tell if you are doing this already in the navigation tag, but I would suggest using the material sidenav component [https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview)

Comment: I am using the material sidenav component.  Does my use of fxLayout look ok/acceptable?

Comment: It looks like it for the most part. Are trying to style the child elements of the first `div`? If so, you should use `fxLayoutAlign` instead. As for your sidenav rendering issues, you would need to post the code of your navigation component as well. You may be implementing the sidenav-container incorrectly, but I can't know without seeing the code.

Comment: @ender I added the navigation component.  For some reason now it overlaps the rest of the content instead of pusing it to the side when the sidenav is opened...

Comment: Typically you wrap the associated primary content within the `mat-sidenav-container`. The [material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) have some examples. In your case, either all of the view code you've posted, or possibly just your Dashboard code, should be contained within the `mat-sidenav-container`.

Comment: @ender Thanks that helps a lot.  I need to have this sidenav available throughout the application though...  Any idea how that could work?  Should the entire app consist of nested routes where the router-outlet is in the mat-sidenav-container?

Comment: That is how I have set up my applications and it has worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you wrap the associated primary content within the `mat-sidenav-container`.

The [material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) have some examples.

In your case, either all of the view code you've posted, or possibly just your Dashboard code, should be contained within the `mat-sidenav-container`